# Check if filename exist from inline command

Tags: bash

I have a file named input.txt with this contents:

> ...
>   FILE "Edie - Realities.txt" TXT
>   ...

And I want to read it, then strip filename path from line that starts with FILE, and check if it exists, so:

`[ -f $(cat input.txt | grep FILE | grep -o "\".*\"") ] && echo "exist" || echo "does not exist"`

but this outputs:

```
[: too many arguments  
does not exist
```

If I run:

```
echo $(cat input.txt | grep FILE | grep -o "\".*\"")
```

I get what I expected:

```
"Edie - Realities.txt"
```

So why is this, or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` is evidently passing `"Edie`, `-`, and `Realities.txt"` as separate arguments. You need to quote `$(...)` like any other `$variable`, and you probably want to remove the `"`s.

```
[ -f "$(cat input.txt | grep FILE | sed 's/^.*"\(.*\)".*$/\1/')" ] && echo "exist" || echo "does not exist"
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to quote the argument to `-f` -- if you run with `set -x` you'd see the command being performed is `[ -f '"Edie' '-' 'Realities.txt"' ]` which is too many arguments.

```
[ -f "$(sed -e '/FILE/!d' -e 's/FILE "\([^"]*\).*/\1/' input.txt)" ]
```

If you have GNU grep on your system, you can use:

```
[ -f "$(grep -Po '(?<=FILE ").*(?=")' input.txt)" ]
```

Answer (score -1):

For your file  contents

```
FILE "/path_to_file/filename" TXT
```

do something like

```
grep FILE  input.txt | while read line 
  do
    fname=`echo $line | awk -F\" '{print $2}'`  # this separates the line by the quotes
                                                # result is like /path_to_file
    echo $fname # just to check it 
    if [ -f $fname ]
    then
      ls -l $fname
      echo "file exists"
    else
      echo "no file there $file"
    fi
  done
```

Comment: No. You missed the crucial point that `$fname` must be in double quotes. The rest of your code isn't particularly helpful here.